# does windows phone 7.3 OS supports flash and silverlight

Tags: silverlight, flash, windows-phone-7

I am currently working on a windows phone project where i have test the compatibility and I do not know flash and Silverlight is supported or not on windows phone 7.3.
anyone can help ?

Comment: Mobile Flash is dying, so I wouldn't count on it as a long term solution.

Comment: @JamWaffles Mobile Flash is already dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It supports Silverlight for applications, but Flash isn't supported altogether.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply but It supports Silverlight for applications what does it mean?

Comment: I meant that you can write applications in Silverlight, but cannot use it in the webbrowser.

Comment: OK finally it means that window phone OS does not supports Silverlight in IE(browser)